# How to structure my project folder when building a secured NodeJs REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am building a REST API using NodeJS and Express, powered by a MongoDB database. 
I've been struggling for days now trying to get the right folder structure nailed down. So far, I can connect to my database and add new users without an API, but by simply doing GET, POST, etc. requests. I've seen several tutorials online on how to build API using node, but none of them have a more standardized way for setting their folder structure. And that is the reason why I am having such a hard time making it work given my current folder structure.

**Here is my Folder Structure**

```
app  
---models  
------user.js  
---api.js  
---routes.js  
config  
---auth.js  
---database.js  
---passport.js  
public  
views
package.json  
server.js
```

**Server.js**

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 2016;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');


var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.configure(function() {

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

    // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    // required for passport
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'xxxxxxxxx' })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session



});

// routes ======================================================================
// require('./app/routes')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
// require('./app/api')(api, passport);

app.use('/', require('./app/routes')(app, passport));
app.use('/api', require('./app/api')(api, passport));

// error handlers
// Catch unauthorised errors
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401);
    res.json({"message" : err.name + ": " + err.message});
  }
  next();
});

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Live on port ' + port);
```

**api.js**

```
var User = require('./models/user');
var express  = require('express');
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

module.exports = function(apiRoutes, passport){

    apiRoutes.get('/testapi', function (req,res) {
        res.json({SecretData: 'abc123'});
    });

}
```

Every time I hit the endpoint `/testapi` I get the error `"Cannot GET /testapi"`
I think my main issue is how to organize my files and folder properly and import/require them the right way. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

> Server.js

on this line `app.use('/api', require('./app/api')(api, passport));`
Here you are telling Express to use `./app/api` as an middleware by passing "api" and "passport" as arguments.

where you have defined `api` variable ?

Lets assume its a typo.. in that case from "app/api.js" you are exporting a function and you trying to execute it in server.js `app.use('/api', require('./app/api')(api, passport));` which returns undefined.

Express will be expecting a function as middleware not a return value from function.

> app/api.js

on line 4 you have `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);` which doesn't make any sense, because `api.js` has no idea about "app".

Cleanup your server.js and api.js and try again

This tutorial might help [Node with Express](https://scotch.io/tutorials/keeping-api-routing-clean-using-express-routers)